# Is it possible to disable the Controls:HoverButton?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, kinect

Currently creating a Kinect application, just wondering if it's possible to disable the 'Controls:HoverButton' within a hover click event.

Code tried:

```
hoverbutton_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

{
anotherhoverbuttononthesameform.IsEnabled = true;}
```

This method doesn't stop 'anotherhoverbuttononthesameform' hover button from being able to be selected.

Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to do the opposite of what you're describing; it sets the control named `anotherhoverbuttononthesameform` to be enabled. Have you tried setting `IsEnabled` to `false` instead of `true`?